# Can not Where-filter a query with multiple includes getting exception at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Thats my query:

```
   var units = _context.Units.Include(m =>
                    m.Modules.Select(t => t.Tests.Select(q => q.Questions)))
                .ToList();
```

When I add `.Where()` at the end of the `t.Tests` collection I get this exception at runtime:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a
>   navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for
>   reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties.
>       Parameter name: path'

How can I though filter the `t.Tests` collection without getting the error?

Just know I want all the Units/Module/Tests.filter/Questions.filter loaded on the client.

My Model:

EF Model:

```
class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}
```

**Why this is not a duplicate!**

Its a filter problem not only with 1 to N but also N to M relation which can not be easily done with the linq query style shown in the already solved solution.

Comment: How does your model look like ?

Comment: @Nashmár Posted my model!

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Its about Include on many to many with .Where(), See Tests/Questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include` does not work in situations where you would like to filter children. Use an anonymous class instead:

```
var unitsWithQuestions = _context.Units.Select(m => new {
    Unit = m
,   TestQuestions = m.Modules.Select(t =>
        t.Tests.Select(q => q.Questions)
    ).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Now you can iterate `unitsWithQuestions`, and retrieve the relevant parts by referring to `Unit` and `TestQuestions` members of the anonymous class.

Comment: I guess with iterate you mean the filtering is executed on the client as you already did .ToList()! Is that correct?

Comment: ok I could filter it inside the anonymous class. I had to use SelectMany for the Modules.Select and my values are a bit different now. But hey you gave that great hint! Much appreciate it!